# Cannot push to the original git repository after it is moved to BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, git-push

Are GIT repository on a remote machine has been moved into BitBucket. I am able to "clone" from the original GIT repository, but not push into it.

When I try to push into the original Git repository, using Git Bash I get:

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 731 bytes | 731.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: couldn't set 'refs/heads/master'
To //homer/share/StrategyServers/git/gitsmrtullcfg.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to '//homer/share/StrategyServers/git/gitsmrtullcfg.git'
```

*It feels as if the write access from the original has been removed after it was moved into BitBucket.*

**1. What can I do to be able to push into my original repository, and not the one that is in BitBucket?**

**2. Why was the original rendered only read only, when it got moved into BitBucket?**

FYI: I have no idea of what BitBucket is. All I am told that are repository has been moved into it and we just have to keep using the original one.

Thank very much for your help in advance.

Comment: For both of these questions, you'll need to ask your team members/supervisor. If the original repository has been made read-only, then somebody had to do that. Because you've stated that somebody else (presumably from your team) has already told you that you have to keep using the original repository, I'd ask them these questions.

Comment: Also, even though you haven't asked, it may help you to know that [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) is website that hosts git repositories, similar to [Github](https://github.com/). They provide some additional continuous integration tools, as well as some integration with their other services (Jira, Confluence, etc).